Assigning Priority in Cyclic Isomers
In a problem, I was asked to determine whether this molecule is an E isomer or a Z isomer. I didn't know much about cyclic substituents, except for extending them to acyclic digraphs. I did that, but now I am stuck. I cannot proceed with solving the problem because I do not know how to assign priority when the substituent is branched right at the start. How should I proceed to assign priority? An elaborate answer is greatly needed.

It is explained here.

@user55119 I read that before posting this question, but I was not able to understand the answer. I tried it 3-4 times, but I couldn't get it.

Look at the two substituents on the right side of the double bond. Both have S>O>H. The upper one has $\ce{CH2CH2}$ before you move out to the heteroatoms while the lower one has $\ce{CH2CH2CH2}$. The UPPER one wins. On the right side one has S>P>H. Move out one atom. Now S>P while the lower chain has $\ce{CH2}$ one out along the chain. The UPPER chain wins. The double bond has the Z-configuration.
ADDENDUM:
Leonardo: I have added a digraph that more explicitly explains my earlier Answer. The red numbers represent spheres or shells as one proceeds outward from 1 $\ce{\rightarrow}$ 7 to determine priorities. Shells 1 through 4 on the right do not allow for a priority to be determined. In shell 5 sulfur or oxygen has a greater atomic number than carbon. The upper chain has priority. On the left one need only go as far as shell 3. Sulfur or phosphorus has higher priority than carbon. Both priority chains are on the same side of the double bond. It has the (Z)-configuration.
For more assistance go to the Search Bar at the top of the screen and type in "user:55119 CIP".


Sir, you mentioned, "Look at the two substituents on the right side of the double bond. Both have S > O > H. The upper one has CH₂CH₂ before you move out to the heteroatoms, while the lower one has CH₂CH₂CH₂. The UPPER one wins." But I am unable to understand why the upper one wins.
I apologize for troubling you, and I understand that I might sound a bit dumb, but my concerns are real. I sincerely request you to please explain this in detail. Also, if you could please clarify what the symbol '>' means in this context and what you mean by 'move out one atom,' I would greatly appreciate it.

Sir, let's see the left side of the digraph. The left carbon of C=C is attached to two carbons, and each carbon is attached to two chains. Which chain among the two should I compare when assigning priority between the two groups attached to the left side of the C=C? Do I need to apply CIP rules to determine which one gets priority and then compare that with the higher-priority chain of the competitor? I know in this case it is not required, but maybe I will encounter a problem where that is involved. I searched for your answer where this was addressed, but I couldn’t find one.

The Answer to which I referred was the original part of the post.  The CIP rules require that you list the atoms in descending order of at. no. and compare the two sets in descending order. The first difference applies. For shell 3 on the left side there is {S,P} vs. {C,C} where sulfur is greater than carbon on. In shell on the right side there is {S,O} vs. {C,C}. Again, sulfur>carbon. Once you have broken the ties, you stop and ignore the rest of the chain. The CIP Rules are illustrated here.
